# What is the maximum number of territories which may all be bordering each other?

Tags: general-topology

I'm working on a map for a game and I'm having trouble laying things out and am wondering if I'm up against a topological limitation.

What is the maximum number of different territories (non-overlapping regions) that can exist on a 2D surface such that every territory is touching (shares a border of non-zero length) every other territory?

Does the answer change if we allow 0-length (corner) "touches"?

Comment: If corners touch, then you can have infinitely many territories (imagine a circle cut by an infinite number of diameters; each wedge is a territory, and they all meet in the center).  Otherwise, the four color theorem seems relevant.  Of course, this assumes that we are talking about a plane.  The answer is different on a torus, for example.

Comment: In other terms, you are asking what is the largest complete graph which is also planar. It is $K_{\color{red}{4}}$.

Comment: But if you play on the surface of a torus, it is $K_{\color{red}{7}}$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll have to consider whether I want to allow wrapping/toruses.